# Regex to match single or pipe seperated instances of string

Tags: regex

I need to validate an input.  It's a pipe seperated string and could be any of the following:

```
1;100;test <br>
1;100;test|2;200;test2<br>
1;100;test|2;200;test2|3;200;test3<br>
etc...
```

So the individual string is `[0-10];[1-1000];[a-zA-Z]`

And I need to validate any permutation of the above is true.

Comment: Maybe `([0-9]+;[0-9]+;[\w]+\|?)+`?

Comment: `(?:[0-9]|10);(?:[1-9][0-9]{2}|1000);[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, shortened: `(?:\d|10);(?:[1-9]\d{2}|1000);[a-z\d]+` with `m` flag

Comment: @samir - That works apart from the fact that 1;100;test| also hits as a match

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[*Modified, third try*] Regex:

```
((10|[0-9])\;(1000|[\d]{1,3})\;[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*)(\|(10|[0-9])\;(1000|[\d]{1,3})\;[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*)*
```

Comment: test is not a given.  Could be any string

Comment: I had not understood the question, I don't know if I have understood it at all now, would it be this modification?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  That has not worked either.

I need it to match <number>;<number>;<string> but also match <number>;<number>;<string>|<number>;<number>;<string>

But not match <number>;<number>;<string>|

Comment: @Rusty is the match that you need `[#{0-10}] a semicolon [#{0-1000}] other semicolon and [some alpha chars]` undefined times ???

Comment: see above comment.  Note the pipe | seperating the instances

Comment: This one works great.  

Thanks for your persistence.  You are a star :)

Comment: Thank you   it was fun to do it.